# how to access swagger api documentation in browser

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I am using Node Js Express js and swagger, i have written documentation of my api in swagger, which i used to access some months ago.

```
 Now i do not remember the URL which i used to add to browser to read documentation, which i have written in swagger. Please help me finding that URL.
```

Comment: `/documentation`  try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i got the url it is 
http://localhost:6106/api-docs/
i got hint from this page
https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express

```
Express setup app.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.json');

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

Thanks every body